# Find a duplicate in multiple cells with condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have column **Name** with different **Type** (Low, Medium, High).

Then I have multiple columns **Name** and need to check whether there is a duplicate and their Types are not **Low**, and return the duplicated Cells.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12gazwAY-yZ7LFzVd_fqv6vKRrwOav_9D5C-ujlGufmw/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 based on the row 6 (sorry, not 7) OP wants what you've said first

Comment: @player0 just logic. Row 6 (H,B,F,C) translated will be High, Medium, High, High and it is not considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",,IF(1<=
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(A2:A))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(C2:C)))+
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(A2:A))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(E2:E)))+
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(A2:A))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(G2:G, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(G2:G)))+
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(C2:C))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(E2:E)))+
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(C2:C))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(G2:G, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(G2:G)))+
 N(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(E2:E))=
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(G2:G, FILTER(L2:L, M2:M<>"LOW"), 1, 0), COLUMN(G2:G))),
 "yes", "no")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. 
My real sheet has 7 Name columns. So the formula will be very long. Is there any shorter option?

Comment: And it's hard to find the duplicate cells as well